# Calculate the intersection between a path enclosed by a `scope` and another path

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I have constructed a circle using the `through` package. I would like to create a coordinate at the intersection of this circle and another line. Is there a way to do this? I tried to name the path created with `circle through`, but could not get that to work.

Here is the code. I would like to calculate the intersection of the red circle and the dashed line or path named "p0." The red circle is constructed to pass through the point "x1." I believe the problem has something to do with the `scope' command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (x1) at (.4,1.2);
\draw[name path=p0,dashed] (0,.8) node[left] {$p_{0}$} -- ++(2.7,0);

\begin{scope}
\node [draw,red] at (2.4,1.9) [circle through=(x1)] {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, the following code, does not compile, where I try to name the path as advised by @Qrrbrbirlbel:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (x1) at (.4,1.2);
\draw[name path=p0,dashed] (0,.8) node[left] {$p_{0}$} -- ++(2.7,0);

\begin{scope}
\node [draw,red, name path=p1] at (2.4,1.9) [circle through=(x1)] {};
\end{scope}

\fill[name intersections={of=p0 and p1}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt) node[below left] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the code does work if there is another item drawn in between the end of the `scope` command and the attempt to calculate an intersection. The following code is essentially the one posted by @Qrrbrbirlbel, which works even with the `scope` command. The only difference is that we draw the "x1" node before trying to create an intersection.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (x1) at (.4,1.2);
\draw[name path=p0,dashed] (0,.8) node[left] {$p_{0}$} -- ++(2.7,0);

\begin{scope}
\node [draw,red, name path=p1] at (2.4,1.9) [circle through=(x1)] {};
\end{scope}

\fill[black] (x1) circle (2pt) node[left] {$x_{1}$};

\fill[name intersections={of=p0 and p1}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt) node[below left] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The comments below @Qrrbrbirlbel's answer explain that one must use `name path global=` instead of `name path`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naming the path of the node works for me:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (x1) at (.4,1.2);
\draw[name path=p0,dashed] (0,.8) node[left] {$p_{0}$} -- ++(2.7,0);

\node [draw,red, name path=p1] at (2.4,1.9) [circle through=(x1)] {};
\fill[black] (x1) circle (2pt) node[left] {$x_{1}$};

\fill[name intersections={of=p0 and p1}] (intersection-1) circle (2pt) node[below left] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Sorry, in an attempt to strip down my code, I eliminated the source of the problem. I have now edited my original question to include a `scope` command, which creates the issue. I have also explained how placing a command in between the `scope` and the `intersection` command solve the problem. But, I do not understand why.

Comment: @stanford202 You need `name path global=p1` then. Though, it is interesting that it works without `global` if there is another path between the end of the scope and the `name intersections` path.